# How to open local folder in thumbnail view in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

It's quite easy to open local picture files with Chrome or Firefox by right clicking > open with. When I navigate from the address bar into the folder the image is in I get a page like `Index of /Users/horst/Documents/pictures_folder/` and see all containing files listed here. Is it possible to display these files in a thumbnail view in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this solution after having similar trouble.

One such extension, [Local Image Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-image-viewer/lhlckkgdiojkapplglfeomlkjllphilo) allows you to view local folders with thumnails, after clicking a button below the file listing.

You need to make some config changes [as described here](http://dottech.org/163314/how-to-view-local-images-in-chrome-tip/).

Briefly, after installing this extension:

- Go to the extension settings page, chrome://extensions/
- Open the desired folder in Chrome.
- A button labeled **Show Thumbnails** appears at the bottom of the listing.  Clicking this will show thumnails for all images in the folder, below.
- Clicking any thumbnail will display the full fiew.
- (from the dottech page) Just press the space bar to zoom in/zoom out the photo. If you place your mouse cursor over the left and right side of the photo, you will be able to see the “next” and “previous” buttons. You can also click the arrow up button to go back to your file’s parent directory.

Read more at http://dottech.org/163314/how-to-view-local-images-in-chrome-tip/#S1sgoAKCKhvUYWGT.99